# Loop different URLs in one window

Tags: javascript, loops, window

There is a set of URLs. (URL1, URL2, URL3, ...).
I would like open a new window, and open those URLs in the new windows, grab data from each URL one by one.
I am using newWindows.location.replace(URLs[i]); to change the href of the window.
My problem is I cannot find a way to wait for each URL is fully loaded and the data is collected.

p.s.
I a not a professnal programmer. I just trying to use Violentmonkey to grab the data from a table inside a web page. 
The table is like this:

```
<tableclass="fltlist_table">
... 
<tbodyid="flt1">
<tr>
<td>...</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

My code like this:

```
    fetch(newURL,fetchPara).then(function(response) {
if(response.ok) {
    response.formData().then(function(formData) {
    console.log(formData);
});
} else {
    console.log('Network request for products.json failed with response ' + response.status + ': ' + response.statusText);
}
})
.catch(function(err) {
    console.log("Error: "+ err);
});
```

Alright, I finnally solved this problem. My code is below:

```
        //original nextPage.href is http, main page is https.
    newURL = nextPage.href.replace(/http/, "https");


    //New window
    newWindow = window.open(newURL, "FilghtWindow", "directories=no,resizable=no, width=400, height=400");

    newWindow.focus();

    var winLoaded = function(){
        //Collect rest
        finalData = GetData(newWindow.document);

        //Next
        nextPage =  newWindow.document.getElementsByClassName("schedule_down")[0];

        if (nextPage){
            newURL = nextPage.href.replace(/http/, "https");
            newWindow.location.replace(newURL);

        }else{
            //Finish
            console.log(finalData);
            newWindow.close();
        }

    }

    var winUnloaded = function(){
        setTimeout(function(){
            newWindow.onload= winLoaded;
            newWindow.onunload = winUnloaded;
        },0);
    }


    //add handle
    newWindow.onload= winLoaded;
    newWindow.onunload = winUnloaded;
}
enter code here
```

Comment: It sounds like you want to make a get request, rather than redirecting to the page.

Comment: @Kobe Yes, I would like make  a set of requests . But It will be better that a new window displays different URL once a time while the data is being grabed from that URL.

Comment: @TaimoorSuleman I did search for a long time but I did not get any anwser. May because I cannot find the perfect key words to search. And also, I tried several time to post my code. But It always said the the format of the code is not correct or ask me to add some context. I do not know how to do to post the code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As suggested, you'd probably be better off making HTTP requests instead of opening new windows. This can be done using [`fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

```
const urls = ['url1', 'url2', 'url3'];

for (url in urls) {
  fetch(url)
    .then(response => {
      return response.text();
    })
    .then(text => {
      console.log(text);
    })
}
```

Hope this helps. Good luck!

Comment: Hi, vmorsell.Thanks a lot.  The structure of your code is almost my need. I just trying to grab the data from a table inside the web page. And I do not know how to do it with fetch. Please see my code in my question.